# Check for value in drop down before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help in submitting  a form with multiple dropdown with sames values,

**conditions:** if `email` is not selected alert email need to selected else check for value already selected

```
<form method="post" action="record_save.php">
    <div id="student_records">
        <select name="select1">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">email</option>
            <option value="2">firstname</option>
            <option value="3">lastname</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select2">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">email</option>
            <option value="2">firstname</option>
            <option value="3">lastname</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select3">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">email</option>
            <option value="2">firstname</option>
            <option value="3">lastname</option>
        </select>
        <!-- until -->
        <select name="select10">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            <option value="1">email</option>
            <option value="2">firstname</option>
            <option value="3">lastname</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' name='submit'>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: That's fairly simple and it has been discussed over and over on many websites and forums. Just google it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply , i have tried for single drop down its working, need to do for multiple drop down  
$(function() { 

    $('form.studentform').submit(function(){
        if ($('.student_records').val()!='email') {
            alert('please select email');
                return false;
            
        }
    });

});

Comment: Is your goal to check if at least one of the dropdowns has the email option selected?

Comment: -1, exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872499/drop-down-validation-for-duplicates. Instead of repeating the same question, just edit your questions, they will automatically go to the top of the list when you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

I iterate over the selected options and count how many times each occurs. On the first detection of a duplicate I add an error message. I also make sure an email was selected. If there are any errors we alert them otherwise the form gets submitted.

```
(function ($) {

    var form = $('#student_records').parent();

    form.submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var selected = {},
            errors = [];

        form.find('option:selected').each(function (index, elem) {

            var val = $(elem).val().trim();

            if (! selected[val]) {
                selected[val] = 1;
                return;

            } else if (selected[val] == 1) {

                errors.push('Already selected: ' + $(elem).text());
            }

            selected[val] += 1;
        });

        if (! selected[1]) {
            errors.push('Must select email.');
        }

        if (errors.length) {
            alert(errors.join("\n"));
            return;
        }

        form.submit();
    });

}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi thanks For reply "else check for value already selected" for example if i have select firstname in first drop down and trying to select same option in 3 drop down it should alert saying you have already selected this option,

Comment: I improved my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery or JavaScript to check values. Like below:

```
 if (validateTheForm()) { 
    $('#yourForm').submit();
 }

function validateTheForm () {
$(':text, select, textarea').each(function() {  
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {  
        $(this).addClass('errorField'); 
            return false; 
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('errorField').addClass('successField');
        return true;
    }    
});
};
```